# Reversing a jquery animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I am trying to achieve the reverse animation in jquery. I came across toggle function. However i am not sure how to use it. My code for one way animation is the above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#popup').hide();

$('.film').click(function() {
    $('#popup').show(function() {
        $('.film').animate({top: '0px', left: '0px'}, 2, function () {
        });
    });
}); 
});
```

Which is the right wat to do so?

Comment: You mean reverse the animation upon a second click of `.film`?

Comment: Yeah! it could be also a keydown function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to save the original css state of an element to be able to revert the animation afterwards. Below is a simple example:

```
// original state
var v0 = {
    top: $('div').css('top'),
    left: $('div').css('left')
};

// animation targets    
var v1 = {
    top: '50px',
    left: '50px'
};

// on click 'toggle' animation    
var clickCount = 0;
$('div').click(function () {
    if (++clickCount % 2 == 0) {
        $(this).animate(v0, 500);
    } else {
        $(this).animate(v1, 500);
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PenJg/3/

Comment: Actually i want two clicks, one for activation and one for the  reverse effect!